# react useState with JSX.Element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm making a table that shows data

```
const [body, setBody] = useState<JSX.Element[]>()
const reduxSelectorValue = useSelector(state => state.someReducer.value) // [4,5,6,7]
const [thisState, setThisState] = useState<number[]>([1])

useEffect(()=>{
  setThisState(reduxSelectorValue)
)
},[reduxSelectorValue])

useEffect(() => {
  setBody(
    thisState.map((value: number, index: number) => (
      <div
        onClick={() => {
          setThisState((thisState) => {
            const newThisState = thisState.slice()
            newThisState[index] = newThisState[index] + 1 - 3
            return newThisState
          })
        }}
      >
        {value}
      </div>
    )),
  )
}, [thisState])

render(
  <ATableElement body={body}/>
)
```

When I click button there's no change on `body`

How should I have to do it with this problem?

Comment: It is anti-pattern in React to store JSX in a React state. Store the data and render the data stored in state to JSX in the return of a component.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing JSX in state. The state should inform _how_ the JSX you return from the component should be rendered. Or what Drew wrote.

Comment: @AshishKamble The effect directly calls `setBody`, adding `body` to dependency array creates render loop. Probably not what OP is looking for.

Comment: Also: `render` should be `return`.

Comment: @DrewReese thank you for your comment. I'm not sure about using JSX.Element in useState, but you awaken of that.

Comment: @Andy thank you for your comment. I'm not sure about using JSX.Element in useState, but you awaken of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you might approach the problem.

1. Have one state where you're storing the array of numbers.
2. `map` over the state to create the buttons. You can make them children of the `ATableElement` if you need to have a container made from another component.
3. When a click listener is called call the `handleClick` function. This works out the index of the button within the container, copies the state, and then updates the index of that new state. You can then set the state with that updated array.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

function Example() {

  const [ state, setState ] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4]);

  useEffect(() => console.log(state), [state]);

  function handleClick(e) {

    // Destructure the children from the parent of
    // the element that was clicked (ie
    // all the input elements)
    const { parentNode: { children } } = e.target;

    // Find the index of the button that was clicked
    const index = [...children].indexOf(e.target);

    // Copy the state
    const newState = [...state];

    // Toggle the boolean at the index of
    // the `newState` array
    newState[index] = state[index] + 1 - 3;
    
    // Update the state
    setState(newState);
    
  }

  return (
    <ATableElement>
      {state.map(n => {
        return (
          <button
            onClick={handleClick}
          >Click {n}
          </button>
        )
      })}
    </ATableElement>
  );
};

function ATableElement({ children }) {
  return <div>{children}</div>
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: thanks. i couldn't think to use children..

Answer (score 0):

Try this correction:

```
const reduxSelectorValue = useSelector(state => state.someReducer.value) 
// [4,5,6,7]
const [thisState, setThisState] = useState<number[]>([1])

useEffect(()=>{
  setThisState(reduxSelectorValue)
)
},[reduxSelectorValue])

body(list){
 let bodyContent = list.map((value: number, index: number) => (
    <div
      onClick={() => {
        setThisState((thisState) => {
          const newThisState = thisState.slice()
          newThisState[index] = newThisState[index] + 1 - 3
          return newThisState
        })
      }}
    >
      {value}
    </div>
  ))
  return <ATableElement body={bodyContent}/>
}

render(
    return body(thisState) 
)
```